# making ellipse markers with error bars matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to make a plot (with errorbars) with ellipses as markers. After some searching I came up with `Ellipse` in `matplotlib.patches`. Then I could draw the error bars with `plt.errorbar`. But the problem is that even though I give the error bar command first, the error bars are always drawn in the foreground and the ellipses are drawn on the background, no matter what order I give in the program.

Does any one know of a better way to create an ellipse as a marker (each point will have a different eccentricity) with error bars? Or at least guide me in how to put the error bars in the background?

Here is a minimal example of what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

PlotFileName="test.pdf"
pdf = PdfPages(PlotFileName)
fig=plt.figure(1)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.xlim([1,4])
plt.ylim([2,8])
ax1.errorbar([2.5], [5], yerr=[1], fmt="o", color="black", ms=0.1)
ax1.add_artist(Ellipse((2.5, 5), 1, 1, facecolor="green", edgecolor="black"))
pdf.savefig(fig)
pdf.close()
plt.close()
```

and here is how it looks:
[image: error bar infront of ellipse]

I want the error bar to go in the background of the ellipse.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am just guessing, but could you try to do the plot in two steps: first plot only the errorbars (i.e., plot your data with errorbars and some kind of empty or minimal markers) and afterwards plot the same data with ellipses as markers but without errorbars (which you have already drawn in the background) ?

Comment: Thanks Jakob, but since I am not exactly a professional, could you guide me in how to plot in two steps?

Comment: Just invoke the "pylab.plot" command twice with different settings. Could you post some minimal example source code?

Comment: I just added a simple case of what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [zorder](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder) specifier for both your plot commands.
From the documentation: "Set the zorder for the artist. Artists with lower zorder values are drawn first."

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

fig=plt.figure(1)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.xlim([0,5])
plt.ylim([0,10])
ax1.errorbar([2.5], [5], yerr=[1], fmt="o", color="black", ms=0.1, zorder=1)
ax1.add_artist(Ellipse((2.5, 5), 1, 1, facecolor="green", edgecolor="black",zorder=2))

plt.show()

exit(0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly. I didn't know "zorder", it is really useful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Working with Path]It seems to me using `Path` is a more straightforward approach: the `Path` instance is treated exactly as a normal `marker`, hence just use the very same interface. Please have a look at the example below, but also reference [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/shapes_and_collections/marker_path.html) on this topic.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.path as mpath

# Create mock data.
theta = np.linspace(0, 2.*np.pi, 30) 
signa = np.sin(theta)

u_theta = np.random.normal(0., scale=0.15, size=signa.size)
u_signa = np.random.normal(0., scale=0.15, size=signa.size)

theta += u_theta
signa += u_signa

# Define the ellipse marker.
circle = mpath.Path.unit_circle()
verts = np.copy(circle.vertices)
verts[:, 0] *= 1.618
ellipt_marker = mpath.Path(verts, circle.codes)

# Done, basically.[![Plotting example][1]][1]
plt.errorbar(theta, signa, xerr=u_theta, yerr=u_signa,
             marker=ellipt_marker, linestyle='', capsize=5,
             ms=20, mfc='w', c='r', mec='g')

plt.xlabel('Autology', fontsize=35)
plt.ylabel('Eterology', fontsize=35)
plt.show()
```